# Why Is $y=|x|$ A Cone?

Tags: geometry

Looking at

$$y=|x|$$

is an example of a cone that is not convex.
It is not convex because for $x_1=(1,1),x_2=(-1,1)\in \{x,|x|\}$ there is not $t\in[0,1]$ s.t $tx_1+(1-t)x_2\in \{x,|x|\}$

But why is it a cone?

Comment: Define a cone. ${}{}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews for all $\alpha > 0$, we have that $\{\alpha x, \alpha |x|\}\in C$ Where $C=\{x,|x|\}$?

Comment: This should read $( x, |x|) \in C$ as they are points in $C$ not subsets. For example for the point $(1,1)$ then the set $\{x , |x|\}=\{1\}$ which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The locus of points where $y = |x|$ is indeed not convex. It's rays that meet at the origin.

You probably mean that the set of points where $y \ge  |x|$ is a cone.

Draw a picture.

Comment: I will be more precise the set $C=\{x,|x|\}$ is a cone, but is not convex.
is it a cone because for all $\alpha>0$ also $\alpha \cdot C \in C$$?

Comment: If that is your definition of a cone (and it's a reasonable definition) then yes it is a cone, but not convex.